# Angular 6 - can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular6, ngx-translate

I am trying to build an application with Angular 6 and I am still setting everything up. But it seems there is something wrong with the dependency injection in my app.

It cannot resolve any constructor parameter. They all result in `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).`. Even a custom service results in the same error.

**Versions** *(omitted the dependencies that can't have any influence on this)*

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.5",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "6.0.8",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "webpack": "4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.4",
  }
```

---

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

---

**TestService.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor() {
    console.warn("It works!");
  }

  public sayHello(): string {
    return "hello world!";
  }
}
```

---

**App.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from "./TestService";

@Component({
  selector: 'sh-home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss'],
  templateUrl: './home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(testService: TestService) {
    testService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

**The injection of the `TestService` gives the error in this case**

---

**Main.ts**

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import './assets/scss/styles.global.scss'; // Import the global scss files

// Polyfills
import './Polyfills';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

---

**Polyfills.ts**

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

I am not using the CLI, but a custom starter. I included all the same polyfills as Angular-CLI does, so I am not missing any.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

---

**Update**

I've simplified the test case and noticed that it is not the translation module. Even if I create a simple service I cannot use dependency injection. Adding the service to the `providers` list doesn't work either (and also shouldn't be necessary, since I am using the Angular 6 '`provideIn: root`').

Comment: have you added this service : ``TranslateService`` in app.module.ts under ``providers : []`` ?

Comment: Tried, but no success :(

Comment: what's is the error

Comment: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am having the exact same problem

Comment: @steven.westside, I have given up on this problem. I stopped using the starter and switched to the CLI. So unfortunately no, I havn't found a solution to the problem.

Comment: ok, thank you, this is really annoying..

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy Did you fixed yet? I am having the same thing over here. It was working previously and now its not. Tell me how did you fix it?

Comment: @Robin, unfortunately I have to give you the same answer as I gave Steven, no solution yet. I switched to the CLI and gave up on my starter.

Comment: Hello; Did u find a solution for this problem?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439224/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-appcomponent

Answer (score 30):

Make sure you have following import in polyfills:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Comment: I am importing `'core-js/es7/reflect'` so I guess that can't be it :(

Comment: Added `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` in `test.ts` and problem resolved for me.

Comment: nearly lost all my hair already, thx that worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 8):

I also got this issue but setting **emitDecoratorMetadata": true** in tsconfig solve the issue. Remember to restart the server.

tsconfig.spec.json

```
   "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this error by just restarting app. build it again and run it, it's works fine for me. Please check and tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes it works thank you.
But now this API gives CORS error how to fix this .


*http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=Client.join*

Comment: Use below lines in your .htaccess

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://localhost:4200'
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

Answer (score 3):

`GET /` or compiler error `can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).`

Just follow these simple steps :

1. Install core-js modeule.

`npm i core-js`

2. In the `polyfills.ts` file add the import statement

`import 'core-js/es7/reflect';`

3. In `main.ts` file add the import statements

`import 'core-js/es6/reflect';`

`import 'core-js/es7/reflect';`

Answer (score 2):

@Inject did the trick for me

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from "./TestService";

@Component({
  selector: 'sh-home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss'],
  templateUrl: './home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(TestService) testService: TestService) {
    testService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: It may work, but according to the Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) this should be the same as just using `constructor(testService: TestService) {}`. So there must be something wrong with the Angular dependency injector.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the below changes:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from "./TestService";

@Component({
  selector: 'sh-home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss'],
  templateUrl: './home.html',
  viewProviders: [TestService]
})
export class HomeComponent {
   constructor(private testService: TestService) {
     this.testService.sayHello();
   }
}
```

**viewProviders** creates a special injector that resolves dependencies only for this component.

Comment: But that would mean I will have to do that in every single component and with the Angular-cli I won't have to do that. So there is something I am missing..

Comment: Did u find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error on Angular 8 app

> Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?,?,?)

after changing 1 parameter type in the constructor().

**I solved the problem by stop and restarting the app.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a component in Angular 8. The constructor had multiple services as parameters.

e.g.,

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private fooService: FooService,
  private barService: BarService,
  private fubarService: FoobarService,
  private anotherService: AnotherService)
{}
```

Experimenting with `@Inject()`, some parameters will take it, but others will not. They will complain about the parameter type.

The common thing about `FooService, BarService and FubarService` was they were physically in the same directory. I created some subdirectories and put one service in each sub-directory -- and the compiler error went away.

[A blog post](https://blog.nigelsim.org/2019/11/27/cant-resolve-all-parameters/) said [forwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef) worked for them. It did not work for me. However, their article provided insight into what might be going on.

Edited to add:

In two other cases, the above wouldn't work. In one case,  changing the import of the service from full path (`src/app/...`) to relative path  removed the compiler complaint (go figure). In the second case, adding `@Inject(ServiceName) public service: ServiceName` resolved the issue.

In all of the above cases, an Ionic 5 project that uses Angular had no compilation complaints. The Ionic project is using Angular 8.2.14. The Angular project is using 8.2.0 (defaults of the respective CLIs when I created the projects).

Looks like some bug is lurking somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue with Angular 8.2.13 + Typescript. Finally the trick was to use a `@Inject('RefOnlyUsedForTesting')`, even if the type is `string`.

```
export abstract class MyBaseClass {
  ....
  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef,
          @Optional() @Inject('RefOnlyUsedForTesting') dep1: MyObject,
          @Optional() @Inject('RefOnlyUsedForTesting') dep2: string,
          @Optional() @Inject('RefOnlyUsedForTesting') dep3: string) {
  super();    
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack and babel to build Angular, it is likely you are missing this babel plugin:
babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines in "main.ts" solved the problem for me:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```