# Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I just migrated an application module to be an importable library.

I'm trying to make the tests work correctly, just as they worked before, but I get this error:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
at syntaxError (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1275:17)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:11176:35)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:11069:26)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10937:24)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10747:35)
at eval (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10861:51)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10849:49)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10747:35)
at eval (webpack:///C:/Repositories/MyProject/my-library/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10861:51)
```

I've seen these possible solutions:
[Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434713/error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-applicationmodule) and [Cannot resolve parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913136/cannot-resolve-parameters-for-applicationmodule) but they cannot fix my problem.

**projects/my-library/src/test.ts**

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Let me know if you need more information to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: What's in your ApplicationModule? Can you post it?

Comment: There is no `Application Module`. I found out what the error was, I'm going to post it in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last, I found where the problem was, I had a hard time finding it because it was not related. The problem comes from this tslint configuration:

**tslint.json**:

```
...
"ordered-imports" [
  true,
  { "named-imports-order": "lowercase-last" }
]
...
```

Even if the configuration is only `"ordered-imports": true` it was causing a problem in `test.ts` file when `ng lint` is launched, so I changed that file to fulfill the tslint requirement:

**test.ts**:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect'; // <-- Moved from the top of imports
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // <-- Moved from the top of imports
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'; // <-- Moved from the top of imports

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

And this file was causing the error I was getting. This file must look like this:

Correct **test.ts**:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

For angular 7 and higher, try adding in polyfill.ts file :

`import "core-js/features/reflect";`

Comment: A little more explanation would help a lot to make this a more useful answer - and would be more likely to get yours upvoted

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Paths have changed in newest version of core-js (3.0.1). If you were using polyfilling and then upgraded your version, this issue would happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency in your app module that you did not provide or import in any way. You can determine which by looking at your `ApplicationModule` constructor method - it likely has some service or similar injected, and you didn't provide it there in `imports` array of `NgModule` metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in polifills.ts file

```
 import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Comment: A little more explanation would help a lot to make this a more useful answer - and would be more likely to get yours upvoted